# Can I filter out certain rows/records when retrieving data from Salesforce using the RForcecom function "rforcecom.retrieve"?

Tags: r, salesforce, filtering

Thanks for helping me with my first Stack Overflow question. I am trying to retrieve all the data from several fields in an Object called "Applied Questionnaire"; however, I do not want to retrieve any records that have the name "Training Site".

Currently, this is my code, which works:

```
quarterly_site_scores = rforcecom.retrieve(session, "AppliedQuestionnaire__c",
c("Site__c", "Site_Name__c", "Total_Score__c")) 
%>% rename(site_id = Site__c, site_name = Site_Name__c)

quarterly_site_scores = quarterly_site_scores[!(quarterly_site_scores$site_name == "TRAINING PARK SITE" |
quarterly_site_scores$status != "Completed"),]
```

However, I'm wondering if there's a more elegant, streamlined solution here. Can I filter at the same time I retrieve? Or is there a better way to filter here?
(I've simplified the code here - I'm actually pulling in about ten fields and filtering on about five or six criteria, just in this one example).

Thank you.

Comment: https://www.displayr.com/querying-data-from-salesforce-using-displayr-and-r/

Comment: Thank you! I would have to pay for displayr so that's not good for my use case, but I'll re-start my search using some hints their blog left (soqlQuery).

Comment: For anyone curious, the answer is to use SF's version of SQL, called SOQL:

`ped_objects = rforcecom.getObjectList(session)
aqb_object = rforcecom.getObjectDescription(session, "InspectTHIS__AppliedQuestionnaireBundle2__c")

aqb_fields = "SELECT Site, Site_Name, Total_Score
               FROM AppliedQuestionnaireBundle2 
              WHERE Site_Name__c != 'GENERIC SITE'
                AND Site_Name__c != 'TRAINING PARK SITE'
                AND InspectTHIS__Status__c = 'Completed'

quarterly_site_scores = rforcecom.query(session, aqb_fields)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding what the OP discovered as an answer using the [**salesforcer**](https://github.com/StevenMMortimer/salesforcer) package which returns the SOQL resultset as a `tbl_df`.

```
library(salesforcer)
library(tidyverse)
sf_auth(username, password, security_token)

# list all object names in a Salesforce org
ped_objects <- sf_list_objects() %>% .$sobjects %>% map_chr(~pluck(., "name"))

# list all the fields on a particular object
fields <- sf_describe_object_fields('AppliedQuestionnaireBundle2__c')

# write a query to retrieve certain records from that object
site_scores_soql <- "SELECT Site__c, 
                            Site_Name__c, 
                            Total_Score__c 
                     FROM AppliedQuestionnaireBundle2__c 
                     WHERE Site_Name__c != 'GENERIC SITE' 
                       AND Site_Name__c != 'TRAINING PARK SITE' 
                       AND Status__c = 'Completed'"
# run the query
quarterly_site_scores <- sf_query(site_scores_soql)
quarterly_site_scores
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>   Site__c Site_Name__c Total_Score__c
#>   <chr>   <chr>                 <dbl>
#> 1 A       Site Name1               78
#> 2 B       Site Name2               52
#> 3 C       Site Name3               83
```